# Different value after fuction call

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class

```
class player{
private:
    int x;//coordinates
    int y;
public:
    player() {}
    player(int px, int py) {
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }
    int get_x() {
        return x;
    }
    int get_y() {
        return y;
    }
```

and a class avatar that inherit from class player:

```
class avatar :public player {

public:
    avatar() {}
    avatar (int px, int py) :player (px, py) {
        cout << "Make a avatar in this coordinates" << " " << px << " " << py << endl;
    }
```

I do

```
void start(avatar &av){
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    (in the end of the fuction)
    cout << endl << avatar .get_x() << ", " << avatar.get_y();
}

int main()
    avatar pl;
    start(pl);
    cout << endl << player.get_x() << ", " << player.get_y();
```

and the results i am getting are

6, 8(right answer)
-858993460, -858993460(after the function,wrong answer)

i dont understand why that happen. I use by reference function call(&)

Comment: You didn't show us the constructor of `player` so there's no way for us to tell you what it's doing wrong.

Comment: "a fuction that inherit from class" - a function cannot inherit from a class. You're using the wrong terminology in that statement.

Comment: sorry guys i edited my mistakes

Comment: You still have a lot of mistakes. You have a `player` definition and a `Figures()` constructor. If you don't post the actual code, we won't be able to help you. We can't just help you on an imaginary code that doesn't reflect what generates the problem, especially if it is incorrect.

Comment: Your default constructors doesn't initialize any members...

Comment: `start()` takes an `avatar&` reference, but `main()` is passing it an `avatar*` pointer instead. That will not compile. Change `start(&pl);` to `start(pl);`

Comment: my real code has figures as a name im sorry for that.

Comment: @ManosW then please stop posting fake code that doesn't even compile. Post your real code (or a slimmed down version of it). Always post a [mcve] (emphasis on **compilable**, unless the question is about a compiler error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in the code you have shown.

But, the most important mistake that can cause the behavior you are experiencing is that you are default constructing an `avatar` object in `main()`, but neither of your default constructors in `player` or `avatar` are initializing the `x` and `y` data members, so they will have *indeterminate* values. That is why you see garbage in your output.

You need to initialize `x` and `y`, eg:

```
class player{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    player() : x(0), y(0) {} // <-- HERE
    ...
};
```

Alternatively:

```
class player{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    player(int px = 0, int py = 0) { // <-- HERE
        x = px;
        y = py;
    }
    ...
};
```

Otherwise, you need to construct the `avatar` object in `main()` with initial values, eg:

```
int main()
    avatar pl(6, 8);
    ...
}
```

Comment: O'rly? That second example is something else lol! Not gonna initialize the members in the init list or declare the ctor explicit eh? Tsk tsk! ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious of course using an init list and explicit are good practices, but they won't change anything in such a simple example, and they are not the issue at hand anyway.

Comment: @ManosW. then that is a completely different issue related to different code you have not shown here, because the code you have shown here creates only 1 object. If you are having a new problem, post a new question about it